# Can't run exe file from cmd in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd, exe

I try to run an exe file from cmd that I open by Java, but nothing happens.
The cmd that oppened seems like:

```
C:\>file.exe
C:\>
```

When I open manually cmd the exe file runs. the cmd seems the same in both cases! (manually and via Java).
My code is:

```
File projDir = new File("C:/");
String command = "cmd /c start file.exe";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, projDir);
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: what have you actually tried? Show your code... As is nobody is going to be able to tell you anything except "you must have done something wrong".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, I found a parallel way to run the exe file, and this way works:

```
List<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
args.add("path\\of\\exe\\file");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
pb.start();
```

anyway - thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need run  an exe thru `cmd`. This should be enough:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("file.exe", null, projDir);
```

and thru cmd with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd","/c","start file.exe"}, null, projDir);
```

Comment: and always keep http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html close...